# Model validation: Pearson residuals vs fitted values - when should I switch model due to heteroscedasticity?

Tags: r, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I'm carrying out GLMMs at the moment on coral reef fish count data against a number of covariates. My response variable data is pretty highly zero-inflated (66.7 percent). I experienced overdispersion and so after checking some other things, moved up from a Poisson to Negative binomial. I simulated my data (created 1000 simulated datasets) to see if the model could handle 66.7% zeros and found that value to be totally fine (see figure 2). However, when I did my model validation I found that my pearson residuals vs fitted graph (figure 1) shows some heteroscedasticity (slightly cone-shaped). I know that in reality these graphs aren't usually perfect but is mine problematic? And would switching to a Zero-inflated negative binomial fix the issue especially since I don't have an issue with zero-inflation.

Here are the graphs.... Thanks!
[image: figure 1 - Pearson residuals vs fitted values]

[image: Figure 2 - histogram showing percentage of zeros in 1000 simulated datasets with det dot showing my response variable number of zeros]

Comment: When using a count-based dataset, you need to use specialized regression designed for the most common characteristics of this type of data: it's often skewed (not normally distributed) and sparse (that's your variance issue). There's no way to 'handle' the heteroskedasticity here because that's the very nature of this data. You didn't say if you set the family to account for this. If you did, then you have misunderstood the assumptions of this type of analysis. [Perhaps this could help](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/)?

Comment: The issue with using a glm (poisson regression) is I need to be using glmms because my data is nested (requiring a 2-way nested glmm) and needs to incorporate random effects. The family set in the model is negative binomial. 
This is my code to produce the model:
 
'MNB1 <- glmmTMB(Abundance ~ All_predators + Year + Location + Depth +
                 (1 | Site/Site.Transect),
               data = plandat,
               family = "nbinom2")'

Comment: Poisson is one of a few options that I know of for count-based regression; there are a few other options out there, some of which support effects. [How about this resource?](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/04/compare-mgcv-with-glmmtmb/)

Comment: Thanks @Kat, do you know if these count-based regressions (negbinom, poisson, zif etc etc) can handled nested design?

Comment: I think you're asking if the R functions can handle it (the algorithms can, of course). That being said, [here's a Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/431692/how-does-random-variable-nesting-in-gams-work-mgcv) that explains how to set up with `gam` or `mgcv` type models. [This is another great resource](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed).